# Retrieving collection filtering by child collection in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm learning Firebase now and I need to retrieve all products that belongs to all user groups a user has access to.

```
{
  products: {
    "prod1": {
      "name": "Product 1",
      "user-groups": {
        "usergroup1": true,
        "usergroup2": true,
        "usergroup3": true
      } 
    },
    "prod2": {
      "name": "Product 2",
      "user-groups": {
        "usergroup3": true
      } 
    }
  },

  usergroups: {
    "usergroup1": {
      "name": "User Group 1",
      "users": {
        "user1": true
      }
    },
    "usergroup2": {
      "name": "User Group 2",
      "users": {
        "user1": true
      }
    },
    "usergroup3": {
      "name": "User Group 3",
      "users": {
        "user2": true
      }
    }
  },

  users: {
    "user1": {
      "name": "User 1",
      "usergroups": {
        "usergroup1": true,
        "usergroup2": true
      }
    },
    "user2": {
      "name": "User 2",
      "usergroups": {
        "usergroup3": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this scenario, user1 must see prod1 only and user2 must see prod1 and prod2.

I did manage to retrieve all products in a certain usergroup, but not considering all usergroups of a user.

```
    this.productsRef = firebase.database().ref('products')
        .orderByChild('user-groups/usergroup1')
        .equalTo(true);
```

Comment: You'll need to iterate over each group and then retrieve the items for the group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I feel more confident to do it.